# umbraco user control form create it's own action

Tags: c#, user-controls, umbraco, umbraco7

I need help with Umbraco user control.

I create a user control to get input from user.

ascx file

```
<form id="formRegister" runat="server">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" type="text" placeHolder="User Name" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the ascx.cs file

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var b = 0;
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a = 0;
    }
```

but somehow when it's loaded i get this in firebug

```
<form id="formRegister" action="/register/" method="post">
```

So the form create it's own action and do that action when I click the submit button instead of the btnSubmit_click event.

What should I do?

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?  What's the code embedding the form in the page?

Comment: umbraco 7.2.8
the code to embed the usercontrol is

    @section content{
 @Umbraco.Field("macroContainer")
}

since this is a template for page that only output a macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User controls won't fire their on click events when loaded as a macro in an Umbraco MVC site. Create a partial view and surface controller instead.

Comment: I have another project which could fire on click event from user control.
But it's Umbraco 4 instead of 7.
So in version 7 we can't use usercontrol for on click event?

Comment: Umbraco 4 is all web forms. If you switch your umbraco 7 site from MVC to Masterpages, it should work the same as Umbraco 4.

Comment: I have googled and changed the template to WebForms but it still didn't fire